# How to select data but without similar times?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with create_dt times and i need to get records but without the datas that have similar create_dt time (15 minutes).

So i need to get only one record instead od two records if the create_dt is in 15 minutes of the first one.

Format of the date and time is `'(29.03.2019 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I'm about to answer and I don't appreciate either of your comments.  Standard SQL will suffice for the answer, and this is a concept people often have problems with, so help with the concept is appropriate.

Comment: @MarlinPierce I don't think Standard SQL can deal with various RDBMS in datetime functions. Unless you only use pseudo code for your query. And OP didn't describe his expected result clearly. What did OP mean 15 minutes? `8h-8h15` interval, or if previous time is `8h09` then the next time upto `8h34` will be omited?

Comment: If I find two rows with only 10 minutes apart, which of the two to keep? The earlier one? The later one? And if I find three rows, each 10 minutes apart from the other (e.g. 10:00, 10:10, 10:20), keep #1 and #3 or keep #2? And if I find 10,000 adjacent ones? Please define the rule, how to decide for the rows to keep.

Comment: @MarlinPierce: especially with date and timestamp arithmetics the various DBMS vary greatly. Not all support the SQL standard like e.g. `create_dt - interval '15' minute` and it might not be that straightforward to translate to the actual DBMS being used.

Comment: @Marlin Pierce: What the OP is probably looking for is a recursive query. Good luck with this.

Comment: I think this is a common problem, and many people do not know to consider joining a table to itself.  I think that is just the help the OP needs, not an exact SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what exactly you want, but one thing I can think of, is to round all values to the nearest "15 minute" and then only pick one row from those "15 minute" intervals:

```
with rounded as (
  select create_dt, 
         date '0001-01-01' + (round((cast(create_dt as date) - date '0001-01-01') * 24 * 60 / 15) * 15 / 60 / 24) as rounded, 
         ... other columns ....
  from your_table
), numbered as (
  select create_dt,
         rounded,
         row_number() over (partition by rounded order by create_dt) as rn
         ... other columns ....
  from rounded
)
select *
from numbered
where rn = 1;
```

The expression `date '0001-01-01' + (round((cast(create_dt as date) - date '0001-01-01') * 24 * 60 / 15) * 15 / 60 / 24)` will return `create_dt` rounded up or down to the next "15 minutes" interval.

The `row_number()` then assigns unique numbers for each distinct 15 minutes interval and the final select then always picks the first row for that interval.

Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e6c7ea651c26a6f07ccb961185652de7

Comment: This is a great solution. But your rounding is flawed. Add `insert into some_table values (timestamp '2019-03-01 11:59:59');` and try it :-) I propose this instead: `date '0001-01-01' + (round((cast(create_dt as date) - date '0001-01-01') * 24 * 60 / 15) * 15 / 60 / 24) as rounded`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: thanks for the bugfix ;) - it also handles `23:59:59` correctly which my code wouldn't have either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to walk you through this conceptually.  First of all, there's a difficulty in doing this that you might not have noticed.

Let's say you wanted one record from the same hour or day.  But if there are two record created on the same day, you only want one in your results.  Which one?

I mention this because to the designers of SQL, there is not a single answer that they can provide SQL to pick.  Then cannot show data from both records without both records being in the tabular output.

This is a common problem, but when the designers of SQL provided a feature to handle it, it can only work if there is no ambiguity of how to have one row of result for two records.  That solution is `GROUP BY`, but it only works for showing the fields other than the timestamp if they are the same for all the records which match the time period.  You have to include all the fields in your select clause and if multiple records in your time period are the same, they will create multiple records in your output.  So although there is a tool `GROUP BY` for this problem, you might not be able to use it.

So here is the solution you want.  If multiple records are close together, then don't include the records after the first one.  So you want a `WHERE` clause which will exclude a record if another record recently proceeds it.  So the test for each record in the result will involve *other* records in the table.  You need to join the table to *itself*.

Let's say we have a table named `error_events`.  If we get multiples of the same value in the field `error_type` very close to the time of other similar events, we only want to see the first one.  The SQL will look something like this:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM error_events A
  INNER JOIN error_events B ON A.error_type = B.error_type
WHERE ???
```

You will have to figure out the details of the `WHERE` clause, and the functions for the timestamp will depend you when RDBMS product you are using.  (mysql and postgres for instance may work differently.)

You want only the records where there is no record which is earlier by less then 15 minutes.  You do want the original record.  That record will match itself in the join, but it will be the only record in the time period between its timestamp and 15 minutes prior.

So an example `WHERE` clause would be

```
WHERE B.create_dt BETWEEN [15 minutes before A.create_dt] and A.create_dt
GROUP BY A.*
HAVING 1 = COUNT(B.pkey)
```

Like we said, you will have to find out how your database product subtracts time, and how 15 minutes is represented in that difference.

Comment: Of course another difficulty with what you are trying to do is what if there are three records 14 minutes apart.  You want the oldest record, but not the second oldest.  What about the third record?  It is within 15 minutes of the second record, but you did not include the second record.  The example I gave would not show the third record because there was a recent record, the second one, in the data.